# New achievement not vertically aligned in container

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

It looks like new achievements in the achievement dialog have a little more padding at the top, making them not vertically aligned anymore (left). The difference is easily seen when you compare it with an old-but-highlighted achievement (right).

[image] [image]

User @Spikatrix [mentions on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387181/unread-items-in-the-achievements-tab-has-some-padding-at-the-top?noredirect=1#comment711735_387181) that the global inbox is affected too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out! This was actually supposed to have padding on both the top and the bottom but another rule was canceling it out. It should look cleaner now.