# Unread items in achievements popup have more height than read ones

Tags: bug, design, achievements-dialog

I noticed that unread items in achievements popup have more height than the already read:

> [image: unread]

The red line is for comparing with background page. Nothing changed, just achievements popup has reopened:

> [image: read]

The number of visible items in popup is also changed (on the latter image “last 30 days” option is displayed) since the total height is constant.

Answer (score 4):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), according to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331078/295232) by a Stack Exchange employee on one of my questions.

> This was actually supposed to have padding on both the top and the bottom but another rule was canceling it out. It should look cleaner now.

I suppose the extra padding improves accessibility; some users might have trouble seeing the blue-gray background and would otherwise have no other indicator that an item is new. For me personally it isn't necessary, but I'm too lazy to write a userscript / custom stylesheet to remove it.

Comment: I don't think the asymmetry is by design -- nothing in that answer says that read and unread messages should be different.  Also, that answer is a month old but I'm seeing this extra padding for the first time today.

Comment: I'll admit that that answer is open to multiple interpretations. Since this question is tagged [bug], chances are one of the SE developers will clarify.